# Blackberry Error: Jar Command Failed

Tags: blackberry, error-handling, compiler-errors

Following is the error I get

> Error: jar command failed:
>
> jar -cfm "E:\Blackberry
> Workspace\Kenexa\deliverables\Standard\7.1.0\Kenexa.jar"
>
> C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local ... Packaging project Kenexa failed (took
> 8.81 seconds)

Project was just working fine, and it suddenly occurred.
I have read the forums they said to set the environmental variable for the jdk to the system and also some said to place the jre exe file in jdk something like this, I did both the options but still not working and I get this error.

But when I delete some classes it starts working and adding new classes again gives this problem, I have total of 22 classes right now, is this something related to size or limitations??

Thanks for the Help!

Comment: OPen up a command-line window and type the command "jar"
 
If the jar.exe program does not execute, then you have a PATH issue. Modify your windows path to include the JDK/bin directory.

Comment: I have set the path but its happening again

Comment: The problem is still there and I have typed jar command in window's command line and it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from [Blackberry Support](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/why-cause-more-then-100-compiled-classes-packaging-I-O-error/m-p/520282) Are you using the BlackBerry JDE or BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse?

If you are using the BlackBerry JDE you could be running into an issue where you have reached the maximum supported length for a command line (all files are listed on a command line). If this is the case you could resolve it by reducing the number of classes (as you have done) or by reducing the length of the path to your source files (move them closer to the root of your drive). Mark Sohm BlackBerry Development Advisor

So, I just have to change my workspace folder name from "Blackberry Workspace" to "Workspace". The command line was not taking long path.