# Blackberry Packaging project Kenexa failed

Tags: blackberry, jar, package

I'm getting this error from a while. I have 28 classes in a project and when I run it fails to  make the package. It says:

```
"Error: jar command failed: jar -cfm "E:\Blackberry Workspace\Kenexa\deliverables\Standard\7.1.0\Kenexa.jar" C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local ...    Kenexa      
line 0  BlackBerry Packaging Problem"
```

But when I limit the classes to 24 then it makes the package. Is it related to some size limit while making the package? What should I do to make the package successfully?

Thanks

Comment: You asked this already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249011/blackberry-error-jar-command-failed

Comment: Yeah, still no answer though :(

Comment: And no answer this time either. Big surprise. StackOverflow frowns on duplicating questions.  if you want more attention, try offering a bounty by putting up some of your own rep. This will make it a featured question.

Comment: Yeah, I will still 13 hours to go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from [Blackberry Support](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/why-cause-more-then-100-compiled-classes-packaging-I-O-error/m-p/520282)
Are you using the BlackBerry JDE or BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse?

If you are using the BlackBerry JDE you could be running into an issue where you have reached the maximum supported length for a command line (all files are listed on a command line).  If this is the case you could resolve it by reducing the number of classes (as you have done) or by reducing the length of the path to your source files (move them closer to the root of your drive).
Mark Sohm
BlackBerry Development Advisor

So, I just have to change my workspace folder name from "Blackberry Workspace" to "Workspace". The command line was not taking long path.